# How do I turn on DB2 syntax in HyperSQL (HSQL)?

Tags: db2, hsqldb

I am trying to use HSQL for testing.  In production, the code runs against a DB2 database.  I would like to turn on the DB2 syntax of HSQL and run the production SQL against it (or as much of it as possible).

According to [the documentation](http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/management-chapt.html), in DB2 syntax mode, the `nextval for` expression is supported.

I've turned on DB2 syntax mode both with the connection property, `sql.syntax_db2=true`, and with:

```
set database sql syntax db2 true;
```

However, I am not able to use `nextval for`, though the syntax `next value for` works correctly:

```
values (next value for test_seq); -- returns the next value
values (nextval for test_seq); -- results in an error
```

The error is:

```
Error: user lacks privilege or object not found: NEXTVAL
SQLState:  42501
ErrorCode: -5501
```

Am I not correctly activating DB2 syntax mode, or am I doing something else wrong?  I am logged in as SA, so can it be a privilege issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a mistake in the documentation. The DUAL table is supported the same way as in Oracle syntax, but NEXTVAL is an Oracle form used as `test_seq.NEXTVAL`.

The DB2 supports `NEXT VALUE FOR test_seq` and allows NEXTVAL as an alternative to NEXT VALUE. This will be supported in the next release of HSQLDB.

Comment: do you support WITH UR? because i get error even i set db2 syntax

Comment: not in version 2.3.3. may support it in the next version